# Why is_page() returns false when visiting the static page declared as "posts page"

Tags: conditional-tags

First of all, sorry if this is a duplicated question... But I haven't found it in the same terms as I'm asking.

I'm surprised because when checking the conditional `is_page()` in a function executed through my `functions.php` file, it returns false when evaluated in the **page for posts** page.

I was so surprised, that I have checked twice in the DB if WordPress has changed the post_type for this page (lol), but obviously, it is still a **page**, so... why the conditional `is_page()` is returning false if it is indeed a page?

Comment: Because WordPress doesn't consider it a page for the purposes of `is_page()`. Not sure what more you expect?

Comment: But where is this exception registered or described? I haven't found any explanation in the codex (maybe it is, but I haven't found it). @JacobPeattie Even in the case that is registered as the page for posts, it is still a page, and don't understand this behaviour...

Comment: Everything is a web page with the broadest interpretation, but in _WordPress_ terms it doesn't use page templates or the page content, and is replaced with the archive of Posts. The conditional tags are broadly aligned with the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), which you can see does not treat the blog index as a page.

Comment: Also consider that the Conditional Tags are checking information about the _main query_ (i.e. what's in The Loop). On the blog page the main query is populated exclusively with the latest posts, _not_ any page.

Comment: Probably that last comment is the main key to understand it all! But you can't deny that the syntactic formulation of the conditional tag "is_page" isn't the best for this particular case... Thanks for your time @JacobPeattie

Comment: @Capiedge A bit late to the party, but I agree, the naming of this function is really bad, or rather, its declaration. There should be an argument or something to let WP know we care about whether or not the queried object is a page that's using just the posts archive, so, in a sense, we are **querying for the slug**